# Android - FragmentTabHost gives me "No tab known for tag null"

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost

I have an activity that uses a `TabHost` associated with `ViewPager`. Although it works fine, I decided to replace it with `FragmentTabHost`. However, after making some changes, I am getting a rendering exception whose messages is as follows.

```
W/System.err(21723): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
W/System.err (21723):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:326)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:276)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12064)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2707)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1339)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1131)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4611)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
W/System.err(21723):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
```

Basically what I did was to make a class named `IconSwipeyTabsView` which extends `FragmentTabHost` and use in a main activity or fragment. I did a lot of research on Google and StackOverflow but none of them gave me a clear answer. FYI, these are the urls of the two core files.

- [`swipey_tabs_stretched.xml`](http://paulshin.ca/temp/swipey_tabs_stretched.xml)
- [`IconSwipeyTabsView.java`](http://paulshin.ca/temp/IconSwipeyTabsView.java)

If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: If you see IconSwipeyTabsView.java, I didn't set it to null.

See how I initialized tabHost... 

final FragmentTabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = newTabSpec("").setIndicator(view).setContent(..);

Comment: I didn't get this error when I was using TabHost..:(

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `IconSwipeyTabsView.setup(FragmentManager fm)` in your activity?

The `No tab known for tag null` error can occur if the `setup` method in `FragmentTabHost` is not called. In case searching for this error leads others here, make sure to call one of the following after creating your `FragmentTabHost` object:

`FragmentTabHost.setup(Context context, FragmentManager manager)`

`FragmentTabHost.setup(Context context, FragmentManager manager, int containerId)`

Details: [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setup%28android.content.Context,%20android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager%29)